# Flutter app runs fine on Android and web. Doesn't show static text on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, user-interface

My flutter app is building without errors on all 3 platforms. However, only on iOS the app is not rendering static text. Dynamic text (from API or variables) is showing normally. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydvHf.png)

Any idea what could be behind this?

I tried cleaning the build then building again, still not working. I tried both Xcode simulator and a physical iphone.

Comment: Can you share your code here.  and Flutter version that you are using.

Comment: I built most of the app on flutterflow and it was working fine until last night. 
it's flutter 3.13.17.
what part of the code should I share, it's a big app, and the issue is on all pages. only dynamic text is visible.

Comment: can you share  the mainapp file where use something like MaterialApp()